# rowCount() always return 0 if current item is folded

Tags: qt4, qt4.8, qstandarditemmodel

I have a QSortProxyFilterModel which is the model of a QTreeView. And a QStandardItemModel serves as the source model of the QSortProxyFilterModel.

Now I'm trying to get the child count of the current model:

```
// my_filterModel is the QSortProxyFilterModel
// my_model is the QStandardItemModel

QModelIndex currentIndex = my_filterModel->mapToSource(
            ui->treeView->currentIndex());

QStandardItem *currentItem = my_model->itemFromIndex(currentIndex);
qDebug() << "Row count: " << currentItem->rowCount();
```

But I got inconsistent values.

If the current item is folded, I can't get its children, `rowCount()` always returns 0

Otherwise, `rowCount()` returns non zero value.

So, how can I get all the children even if the item is folded?

**EDIT**

Looks like to be a bug of QTreeView. If you have previously unfolded these child items, `rowCount()` returns a valid value; Otherwise it always returns 0

Comment: What model do you use?

Comment: @hank QStandardItemModel

Comment: I've just tested a simple example with `QStandardItemModel` and `QTreeView` and everything works fine. I get corrent rows number no matter whether an item is folded of not.

Comment: @hank I forget to mention, the model of the treeView was a QSortProxyFilterModel, and its source model was a QStandardItemModel (`my_model` here), do you think that matters?

Comment: @hank If you have previously unfolded the child items, it works; otherwise it won't

Comment: @hank see updates ...

Comment: I've added `QSortProxyFilterModel` to my example and it still works. I always get a correct result, and I don't need to unfold my item first. Are you sure that model data is ready when you try to call `rowCount`?

Comment: @hank Yes, I can see the emblem in front of the item, and double click expands it